# Fresh install of codeigniter 404 error or downloads each page

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am migrating from an old Linux server to a new Linux server and have a fresh install of codeigniter on the old one that works perfectly. Transfer it to the new server however, and it gives me a 404 error on the 'home page' (just the domain or the direct route - http://mydomain.co.uk/welcome) or, if I include index.php it attempts to download it!

This is my .htaccess file:

```
options +followsymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|images|module_uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

the base url is correct and `$config['index_page'] = '';`

This is all it takes to run the millions of codeigniters installs I've got on my old server so I've no idea where to start!

I've Googled it all and tried adjusting slashes in the `.htaccess` file and I've added and removed `index.php` in the `$config['index_page'];` so I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: this sounds like you don't have php installed yet.

Comment: try entering command on bash/shell php -v ,if php version is existing, you have wrong configuration on your server

Comment: Hi, I have deleted all files and literally just put an index.html file in with 'hello' in it. This comes up fine, but if I change the file extension to .php and refresh it tries to download the file again. Does this mean the server doesn't have php installed?! This seems a bit ridiculous!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the config.php file in your application/config folder and go down to where it says $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; and delete the index.php part. So it just says $config['index_page'] = '';

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have tried this, but it makes no difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. It turns out after being told by my server people over and over that it's my code that's the problem (tell that to CodeIgniter), it turns out my old server used Apache and my new one uses Fast-CGI. But no-one told me! I've had it changed to Apache and, would you believe it, everything works fine. Hmmm. Not my code then is it. Thanks all.